# why did my .htaccess stop working on deployment

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a codeigniter website which has a broken link structure. It was working correctly in my wamp local environment. However when I deploy to my shared hosting site, the links stop working. The initial page loads normally. My Navbar looks like:

```
<a class="brand" href="#">myproject</a>
          <div class="nav-collapse">
            <ul class="nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li ><a href="http://localhost/projectname/basecontroller/Facts">Facts</a></li>
              <li ><a href="http://localhost/projectname/basecontroller/about">About</a></li>
              <li ><a href="http://localhost/projectname/basecontroller/contact">Contact</a></li>
              <!--<li ><a href="http://localhost/projectname/basecontroller/privacy">Privacy</a></li>-->
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
```

I have deployed my site using git to ~/myaccount/domains/simon. Then I simlinked public_html to ~/myaccount/domains/simon.

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 myaccount myaccount
30 Mar 28 17:35 public_html -> /home/myaccount/domains/simon
```

I've tested it the following .htaccess file in the root directory when I try things locally on wamp:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /projectname/index.php/$1 [L]
```

This appears to fix the directory structure by turning:

```
http://localhost/projectname/basecontroller/contact
```

into:

```
http://localhost/projectname/index.php/basecontroller/contact
```

However this does not appear to work when I push it to my production server. How can I fix this?

Comment: Make sure that your host had mod_rewrite enabled in Apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea, mod_rewrite is black magic. It's a great tool, but you never get consistent results especially when changing from one server to another.

You can try randomly playing with stuff (eg: remove the leading `/` or perhaps remove `/projectname/` or perhaps try setting a `rewrite_base`).

Here's what we use on some of our servers (but it doesn't work on all of them):

First, check if the URL exists on the filesystem and do nothing (images, css, robots.txt, index.php, etc):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L,QSA]
```

Then, if that fails, send all requests to a your PHP file (after checking if the current URL already goes to that file):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php$
RewriteRule ^(/?)(.*)$ $1index.php [L,QSA]
```

Notice specifically that we check for an *optional* leading slash and put it at the start of the URL if it is there. Your code doesn't check and then always puts a leading slash in. That's probably the issue.

Also, you pretty much always want to have QSA in the options list.

Answer (score 1):

Try This,

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine on
Rewritebase /projectname
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|uploads|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

open config.php
then try to change

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

to one of these

```
| 'PATH_INFO'       Uses the PATH_INFO
| 'QUERY_STRING'    Uses the QUERY_STRING
| 'REQUEST_URI'     Uses the REQUEST_URI
| 'ORIG_PATH_INFO'  Uses the ORIG_PATH_INFO
```